# Project Euler problem #111. Generate 10 digit primes with most repeated individual digits

Tags: python

I am working on [project Euler problem #111](https://projecteuler.net/problem=111). I have created this program which works fantastic for the given example but apparently is not producing the desired answer to the problem. Here's my source code in python:-

```
#This function generates all the primes of 4 digits with the highest repeated digits 1 to 9 and returns their sum for eg. 3313, 4441, 4111 etc.
```

Note that any digit from 1 to 9 can come at most of 3 times in a 4 digit prime number. I have highlighted the same in the code.`

```
from more_itertools import distinct_permutations
from sympy.ntheory.primetest import isprime
def fn1to9():
    s = 0
    for digit in range(1, 10):
        for j in range(0, 10):
            permutations = list(distinct_permutations(str(digit) * 3 + str(j)))
            for perm in permutations:
                num = int("".join(perm))
                if (num > 1000000000):
                    if (isprime(num)):
                        print(num)
                        s = s + num
    return s
```

This function is for the special case of 0. Note that 0 can come atmost 2 times in a 4 digit prime no. I have bolded the number 2 in the code.

```
def fnFor0():
    s = 0
    for firstDigit in range(1, 10):
        permutations = list(distinct_permutations(str(0) *2+ str(firstDigit)))
        for perm in permutations:
            for msd in range(1, 10):
                temp = list(perm)
                temp.insert(0, str(msd))
                num = int("".join(temp))
                if (num > 1000000000):
                    if (isprime(num)):
                        print(num)
                        s = s + num
    return s
```

Now, this program works well and produces the desired sum of `273700` as has been stated in the question. So, I made the required changes and ran it for 10 digits. The required changes were changing the `str(digit)*3` to `str(digit)*9` in `fn1to9` and `str(digit)*2` to `str(digit)*8` in `fnFor0` in the `distinct_permutations()` function (Hoping that 9 digits will be repeated for every digit from `1` to `9` in the prime number and 8 `0`s for the prime number containing `0`s). But it did not give the desired answer. Then I inspected and found out that for repeated digits of `2` and `8`, the maximum repetition can be of 8 digits, so I wrote another function specifically for these 2 digits which is as follows:

```
def fnFor2and8():
    s = 0
    for digit in [2,8]:
        for firstDigit in range(0, 10):
            for secondDigit in range(0, 10):
                permutations = list(distinct_permutations(str(digit) * 8 + str(firstDigit) + str(secondDigit)))
                for perm in permutations:
                    num = int("".join(perm))
                    if (num > 1000000000):
                        if (isprime(num)):
                            print(num)
                            s = s + num
    return s
```

This function as expected produces the desired 10 digits numbers with `2` and `8` repeated exactly 8 times. I had hoped it summing up the results from all of these 3 functions will give me the answer but seems like I am missing some numbers. Can someone please help me point out the flaw in my reasoning or in my program. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here was the solution I came by wehn I was working on this problem:

```
import eulerlib


def compute():
    DIGITS = 10

    primes = eulerlib.list_primes(eulerlib.sqrt(10**DIGITS))

    # Only valid if 1 < n <= 10^DIGITS.
    def is_prime(n):
        end = eulerlib.sqrt(n)
        for p in primes:
            if p > end:
                break
            if n % p == 0:
                return False
        return True


    ans = 0
    # For each repeating digit
    for digit in range(10):

        # Search by the number of repetitions in decreasing order
        for rep in range(DIGITS, -1, -1):
            sum = 0
            digits = [0] * DIGITS

            # Try all possibilities for filling the non-repeating digits
            for i in range(9**(DIGITS - rep)):

                # Build initial array. For example, if DIGITS=7, digit=5, rep=4, i=123, then the array will be filled with 5,5,5,5,1,4,7.
                for j in range(rep):
                    digits[j] = digit
                temp = i
                for j in range(DIGITS - rep):
                    d = temp % 9
                    if d >= digit:  # Skip the repeating digit
                        d += 1
                    if j > 0 and d > digits[DIGITS - j]:  # If this is true, then after sorting, the array will be in an already-tried configuration
                        break
                    digits[-1 - j] = d
                    temp //= 9

                else:
                    digits.sort()  # Start at lowest permutation

                    while True:  # Go through all permutations
                        if digits[0] > 0:  # Skip if the number has a leading zero, which means it has less than DIGIT digits
                            num = int("".join(map(str, digits)))
                            if is_prime(num):
                                sum += num
                        if not eulerlib.next_permutation(digits):
                            break

            if sum > 0:  # Primes found; skip all lesser repetitions
                ans += sum
                break

    return str(ans)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(compute())
```